# Fix size for Listview columns and Rows Data

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

[[image: IPhone 5S]]
[[image: MotoG6]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPmf7.png)
[[image: OnePlus6T]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ0eK.jpg)

I am working on the Xamarin Forms App. I encountered a problem where Listview is working fine on Small screen Phones (iOS and Android) but Alignment is not as expected in Bigger size phone.

Please find the code. This is not working in Big screen phone and working fine on a small screen.

The alignment is not appearing correctly in Big screen device please help.

this is happening in Both Environment iOS and Android.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                 xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Uniconta.Views"
                 mc:Ignorable="d"
                 x:Class="Uniconta.Views.ItemList">
        <NavigationPage.TitleView>
            <SearchBar x:Name="Search" Placeholder="Item" HeightRequest="50" TextChanged="OnSearchValueEntered" Text="{Binding SearchedText, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                               SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="-23,0,0,0"  BackgroundColor="#5BC4BF"/>
        </NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout>
        <ScrollView x:Name="scrView" Orientation="Both" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default" WidthRequest="200">

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="MainLayout" Padding="10">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" WidthRequest="320">
                    <views:ImageHolder x:Name="imgHolder"  WidthRequest="300" IsVisible="False"/>
                    <Button IsVisible="False" x:Name="removePhotoBtn" WidthRequest="40" Image="ic_remove" HorizontalOptions="End" Clicked="RemovePhotoBtn_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout x:Name="stDocs" Orientation="Horizontal" WidthRequest="320" IsVisible="False">
                    <views:DocumentHolder x:Name="docHolder" WidthRequest="300" />
                    <Button x:Name="removeDocsBtn" IsVisible="True" WidthRequest="40" Image="ic_remove" HorizontalOptions="End" Clicked="RemoveDocsBtn_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <ListView x:Name="lstView" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always" ItemTapped="LstView_ItemTapped" HorizontalOptions="Center" SelectionMode="Single">
                    <ListView.Header>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="14*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Text="Item" x:Name="lblItem" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#818286"  FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                <Label Text="Item Name" x:Name="lblItemName" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#818286"  FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="Item Type" x:Name="lblItemType" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#818286"  FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ListView.Header>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell Height="40">
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" >
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Item}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,50,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#818286" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#818286" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                            <Label Text="{Binding ItemType}" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" TextColor="#818286" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

Comment: we can't debug code we can't see.  And "not as expected" is not a helpful description of the problem.

Comment: I "ll post the code.

Comment: I still have no idea what problem you're having.  Again, "not as expected" does not helpfully describe the problem.  Perhaps if you posted TWO screenshots comparing the two layouts and explained EXACTLY what is not "as expected" on the bigger size device we would be able to help you.

Comment: Jason is right, post 2 screenshots of big and small devices, and try to point out what's wrong with the bigger device, im guessing it's probably because you are not setting the grid HorizontalOption to fill and expand, and the labels will not center because the parent view is not filling the available size

Comment: Hi Folks, screenshots added for 3 different phones.